# How can I get a class that implements ITemplate to allow duplicate IDs?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itemplate

This works:

```
Public Class HelloWorld
  Inherits CompositeControl
  Implements INamingContainer

  <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
  Public Property TemplateA() As ITemplate

  <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
  Public Property TemplateB() As ITemplate

End Class
```

And:

```
<me:HelloWorld>
  <TemplateA>
    <me:SomeControl>
      <asp:Textbox Id="Bob" />
    </me:SomeControl>
  </TemplateA>
  <TemplateB>
    <me:SomeControl>
      <asp:Textbox Id="Bob" />
    </me:SomeControl>
  </TemplateB>
</me:HelloWorld>
```

But what I'd rather do, is implement ITemplate in a class so I can also use custom properties and other things:

```
Public Class TemplateA
  Inherits TemplateBase
  Implements INamingContainer, ITemplate

  ... Properties

  Public Sub InstantiateIn(container As Control) Implements ITemplate.InstantiateIn
      container.Controls.Add(Me)
  End Sub
End Class
```

But then I get a duplicate ID error for the Textbox. **Can someone please show me an example of this?** I've read through countless templated control tutorials and found examples of people doing this, but apparently it isn't implementing the Itemplate in the same way. Examples in C# or VB.net are fine.

Comment: Duplicate of location found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322405/asp-net-duplicate-ids-and-templated-control-is-there-a-more-elegant-way)?

Comment: Looks like that was my original question. The problem is I'm allowing users to enter their markup in the templated control so I don't see how the answer would work. I really want to figure out the proper way to implement the ITemplate as a class. Thank you for pointing it out as I failed to respond which isn't great. I'll do that now.

Comment: In addition, a separation of templates is more precise for this particular question. <TemplateA> <TemplateB>. I'd be forever grateful for a working example. This has been an off and on battle for a year.